# Extract host name from URL using scala

Tags: scala

I have an RDD extracted from files containing source and destination URLS of the format :

```
google.de/2011/10/Extract-host       link.de/2011/10/extact-host
facebook.de/2014/11/photos           facebook.de/2014/11/name.jpg
community.cloudera.com/t5/           community.cloudera.com/t10/
```

These are the source and destination URLS.
I would like to extract only the host name like for example:

```
google.de                   link.de
facebook.de                 facebook.de
community.cloudera.com      community.cloudera.com
```

I know how to extract the host name if there is only one column in the file using

```
file.flatMap(_.split("/").take(1)).
```

Im not sure how to apply it on both source and destination URLs. 
Here is what i have tried :

```
file.flatMap{case(src + "\t" +  dst) => 
((split.take(1).flatMap(line => line.split("/").take(1))),
(split.takeRight(1).flatMap(line => line.split("/").take(1))))}
```

Please tell me how to extract this format using scala.

Thank you!!

Comment: How you want the output to look like.? Do you want the both the source and destinations urls to be one record separated by some delimiter. Or want everything to be flattened to give only the host name?

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I need only the host name extracted from source and destination URLs separated by some delimiter and my output should like look what I have specified in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input source and destination urls are separated with "\t"

```
val result = file.map(f => {
      val urls = f.split("\t")
      if (!(urls.length < 2)) {
        val result = urls(0).takeWhile(_ != '/') + "\t" + urls(1).takeWhile(_ != '/')
        result
      } else
        null
    })

    result.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: Hi instead of saving it as a string is it possible to map it of the format (a,b) ? Because i need to calculate inlinks and page rank.

Comment: By mapping, do you mean a pair rdd? If yes, you can create a pair rdd by just returning a scala tuple with key value pair as below.val result = file.map(f => {
      val urls = f.split("\t")
      if (!(urls.length < 2)) {
        (urls(0).takeWhile(_ != '/'),urls(1).takeWhile(_ != '/'))
      } else
        (null,null)
    })

Comment: Ya I tried that and I'm able to view the records as well. But I'm getting some error when i try saving it into a file in .gz format.

Comment: Hi I sorted it out. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

A data frame oriented answer :

```
val df_raw = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter","\t")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("your_file.txt")

//if header is false just specify a schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
  StructField("src", StringType, true) :: 
  StructField("dst", StringType, true) :: Nil)

//and add this line to the spark.read :
//.schema(schema)
```

Using an udf function, dunno if this is optimized :

```
val get_domain = spark.udf.register("get_domain",(value:String)=> value.takeWhile(_ != '/'))
```

or

```
val get_domain = udf((value:String)=> value.takeWhile(_ != '/'))
```

And selecting the new columns :

```
val df_final = df_raw
    .withColumn("src_domain",get_domain(col("src")))
    .withColumn("dst_domain",get_domain(col("dst")))
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply.  I have .gz file. When i tried reading it,                                                    
    val df_raw = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter","\t")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("filename.gz") I am getting an error Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") .

Comment: For my use case, I would create a shell file to untar the files to a directory and read them from here. But you should rather use the RDD API I guess. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching:

```
val pattern = """([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/\S*\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/.*""".r

val srcAndDest = rdd flatMap {
  _ match {
    case pattern(src, dest) => Some(src, dest)
    case _                  => None
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. I tried this. But i'm not retrieving any results.

Comment: What is your code which creates rdd from input file?

Comment: Its val file = sc.textFile("filename.gz")

Comment: So when you do    "val lines = srcAndDest.collect;
    println(lines.length);
    lines.foreach(println)" - nothing is printed into console?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is printed into console.